# Как расположить гугл карту на сайт?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3

Есть ссылка на карту следующего вида:

```
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xd39JWDNujOICBukk8Sh5AaZJlU&usp=sharing
```

Как её расположить на сайте через `<iframe>`?

Comment: в поделиться есть пункт встроить на сайт

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=1xd39JWDNujOICBukk8Sh5AaZJlU" width="640" height="480"></iframe>`